# How do I see where a Jupyter Notebook file is in File Explorer?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The main screen in Jupyter Notebook does not correspond to any location in file explorer, though the folders such as Documents and Downloads do, so if a file is there I don't know where to find it when uploading it to somewhere.

Also how do I find where a file is in file explorer when it is open. Also Save As literally only makes a copy with a new name (in the same location) even though it promises to create a "new path". Also Make a Copy does not give the option to make this copy somewhere else.

There is no information on this in the internet, only weird commands with a thousand upvotes with no one mentioning that they don't work or at least don't work in my very normal case.

Note: I was able to solve this problem through the convoluted manner of making a copy, then selecting that copy (because the original file was green and did not give the following option even though I closed all instances and refreshed this page), and clicking Download, which opened File Explorer and gave me the option of where to save it as and in what name.

Comment: How did you launch the notebook server?

Comment: To follow on Paul's question...you'd have to provide more information if you really want to understand what is happening. Chances are it would be less convoluted if you better understood what was happening. There's a lot of ways to be running 'Jupyter notebook' these days. (I use quotes there because it may be even JupyterLab you are using.) It could be local, could be on remote server, could be using JupyterLite which has static files that then get run inside your local browser's machinery actually using web assembly, almost like it is a remote sever running the code.

Comment: Or to look at it another way. You state there, "is no information on this in the internet." If you better understood things now, you may find there is and how to better look in the right places to get those answers. Or if there truly isn't anything, we in the Jupyter community can maybe help fix that so others coming after you don't struggle.

Comment: @Wayne I typed Jupyter Notebook into Windows Search then clicked Enter. I believe it runs local.

Comment: Okay, if running local then when you start a new notebook, you should be able to type `pwd` in a cell in the notebook and it will tell you where it is located on your system. `pwd` means `print working directory`. It can get confusing with a notebook you've been working in because you can change the working directory with `%cd` as you work, but if you start fresh you should be good. The other way to find things is to save the `.ipynb` file and search for the file name as you would on your system normally.